# Connecting to a sql database from an applet on the server, do you use localhost or the actual ip

Tags: java, mysql, applet, mysql-connector, connector-j

I am trying to connect to a database on my website from a java applet. 
When I try from eclipse, it says that there was a communications link failure and that the driver has not received any packets from the server. Is that because only applets on the actual server can connect to a database?

So I exported it as a jar and I personally signed it and uploaded it to my website. Then using as embed tag, I put it in my webpage.

```
<div id="blah">
<embed id="Math"
   type="application/x-java-applet"
   width="810" height="600" 
   archive="mathG.jar,mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar"
   code="com.mathg.math.MathG"
   codebase="test"
   pluginspage="http://java.com/download/"/>
```

Is that the proper way to put the applet on the site? The applet shows up and it works on the webpage, but when I press a button to connect to the database, it says that it couldn't connect.

I tried using both localhost and the actual ip in my java code to try to connect, but neither works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the IP address of the database server is preferred; localhost should only be used for quick & dirty local tests.  It's unlikely that you'll deploy an app or database on localhost.

This is a *very* bad idea.  No applet should have direct access to a database from the internet.    All that data is exposed.

A better idea is to put a servlet in-between the applet and database.  Deploy the servlet by exposing it to the internet; put the database behind a firewall and only open its port to the servlet.  Let the servlet handle authentication, validation, binding, and interacting with the  database.  Users will be much better off with this design.

Comment: So if I used a servlet, would I be able to access the values from the database through the servlet in eclipse? or would I always have to put it on the website to see the output?

Comment: You have to deploy the servlet, of course.  You can start Tomcat in Eclipse.  I don't see how an IDE has anything to do with this question.

Comment: So servlets are run on the server right? And the user doesn't need tomcat installed?

Comment: I don't know about "user".  You have to deploy the servlet on Tomcat running on some server.  Users will contact that server to get the applet, which connects back to the server from which it came to talk to the servlet.